# Maximum 19" screen resolution is 1024x768

Tags: display-resolution, screen

I installed ubuntu on my secondary laptop.
I have 19" screen LG W40series connected via VGA.
Maximum resolution is 1024x768
At the other distro's it worked fine with full hd resolution..
Please help - ubuntu 20.04

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unwz7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try this in a terminal:

```
~$ cvt 1920 1080 (# or whatever you want as your resolution.)
(#Copy what is after the word Modeline)
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync (# paste what is after the word Modeline)
~$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1920x1080_60.00"
~$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00" (# Instead of XWAYLAND1 use the name of your monitor)
~$
```

That's it